# BlackBerry app larger than 14mb

Tags: blackberry, packaging

My BlackBerry app includes some html files, images, jss files. These files are gzip compressed, but the size of this gzip is 18mb. I know that the maximum size of a BlackBerry smartphone application is [about 14 mb](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/The-maximum-size-of-a-BlackBerry-smartphone-application/ta-p/502534).  How can I work around this limit?

I have found this support forums page: [The file size limit for wireless downloads](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/article-id/17)

It suggest use libraries, someone have any experience with this?

Comment: 18 Mb on a Smartphone, you need to make it smaller, these have limited storage, this is not a 1TB hard drive that you have.

Answer (score 1):

Can you download resources from a website as they are needed?  You could always cache locally after retrieving if that will help.

Comment: Well, since this app exists to iphone and android, and in these devices all contents are inside the installer, my company want that in blackberry the contents are inside the installer too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a sample of library project usage, then you can check BB SDK on your PC. It should contain samples. For instance, my API 6.0 SDK has "browserfielddemo" project sample which uses the "commonlib" library project. So it's possible to study the implementation.