# Error!: too much resource data, max allowed

Tags: blackberry

I've some data (image + text files ~ 14MB) placed in folder "res", now it throws "Error!: too much resource data, max allowed..". I've already unchecked "Convert images to png" but still that error is not going away!

Is there anything else which can make it disappear?

Comment: @Nate, I've seen that question but how can I get rid of that issue? Can't download from server, need to keep this much data in res folder.

Comment: What sort of data is this?  BTW, converting images to png might not be a useful thing to do, jpgs are usually smaller and as I understand it, faster on the newer devices.

Comment: @PeterStrange, the question says he already **unchecked** the option to convert to png, so if Khawar's app has jpgs, they're still jpgs.  Also, please see my comment to adwiv below.  This question has already been addressed multiple times here.

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple library projects for Resource Data and then make your app depend on those projects. This way you can overcome the limits.

Comment: This is a fine answer, but the answer by Arhimed in the duplicate I linked to already suggests this.  If you agree, then I suggest you [give that answer an upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5834188/119114).  Continuing to answer questions that are duplicates, instead of just closing them, adds clutter to the site, and makes good questions and answers harder to find.